# Trufffle : VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: solidity, truffle

0

I am using truffle to edit Solidity file.

It is a test file.

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.0;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

contract test111 {
    struct Goods {
        bytes name;
        bytes img;
        bool isClaim;
    }

Goods public good = Goods("123","zx", false);
Goods[] public goodsList;

function getValue() public view returns(bytes memory) { //it can work
    return good.img;
}

function add() public{
    goodsList.push(Goods("123","zx", false)); //VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
}

function getArray() public view returns(Goods memory){ 
   return goodsList[0]; //VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
}

function getLength() public view returns(uint) {
    return goodsList.length; //VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
}
}
```

After deployed,I can see the contract depolyed via Ganacha

I have got a instance first with terminal

```
let instance = await test111.deployed();
```

When i use `instance.getValue()` it returns `0x7a78`, it worked.

But when i try to use `instance.add()` or `instance.getArray()` or `instance.getLength()`. It will notice me

> VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Then I tried in **Remix-Ide** , every method can work without any problems.

[Picture of Remix-Ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfsIY.png)

How can I solve this problem in truffle, thank you.

```
My enviroment:

OS:windows11
+-- ganache-cli@6.12.2
+-- ganache@7.0.4
+-- node-gyp@9.0.0
+-- npm@8.6.0
+-- truffle@5.5.9
`-- yarn@1.22.18
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=VM+Exception+while+processing+transaction%3A+revert

Comment: did you `await` those too: instance.add() or instance.getArray() or instance.getLength()

Comment: @Yilmaz I tried to repeat methods in my company's computer today , it surprised work = =... I think I should try to figure out is there some enviroments problems